# Xstream - Remove ArrayList elements name

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xstream

I have a class like

```
class Account{
  List<String> information;
}
```

XStream serializes to XML that looks like:

```
<information>
      <string>This is sample Info 1</string>
 </information>
```

I wanted the XML like:

```
<Information>
  This is sample Info 1
</Information>
```

so I tried using

```
xStream.aliasAttribute(Account.class,"information","Information");
```

now I have output XML as:

```
<Information>
   <string>This is sample Info 1</string>
</Information>
```

How can I get rid of this `<string>` in XML?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old but perhaps someone will find the answer useful. To do that simply use *@XStreamImplicit* annotation with *itemFieldName* property.
So in this case:

```
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="Information")
List<String> information = Arrays.asList("Sample 1", "Sample 2");
```

Will result in following XML result:

```
<Information>Sample 1</Information>
<Information>Sample 2</Information>
```